# How can I have to conditional and two output in a single lambda?

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I would like to filter variables below two standard deviations and those above to standarf deviations. I know I can do this with def/ return and then apply statement but was wondering if I could somehow do this in a single line with lambda.

I have tried the code below (the numbers in 'No- show' are all int and were the base from which I calculated the median, upper, and lower two standard deviations):

```
df2F['outlier_neighbourhood']=df2F['No-show'].apply(lambda x: 'Lower Outlier' if x <0.6091564238171008 elif 'Upper Outlier' else 'normal')
```

**Error:**

> File "", line 2
>       df2F['outlier_neighbourhood']=df2F['No-show'].apply(lambda x: 'Lower Outlier' if x <0.6091564238171008 elif 'Upper Outlier' else
>   'normal')
>                                                                                                                 ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: elif needs condition like if

Comment: Besides, elif isn't allowed in a ternary expression.

Answer (score 0):

```
lambda x: 'Lower Outlier' if x <0.6091564238171008 else 'Upper Outlier' if x > 42 else 'normal'
```

would be the way to go.